# How to binarize the values in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['Male','Female', 'Female', 'Unknown', 'Male'], columns = ['Gender'])
```

I want to convert this to a DataFrame with columns 'Male','Female' and 'Unknown' the values 0 and 1 indicated the Gender.

```
Gender  Male  Female
Male     1      0
Female   0      1
       .
       .
       .
       .
```

To do this, I wrote a function and called the function using map.

```
def isValue(x , value):
if(x == value):
    return 1
else: 
    return 0


for value in df['Gender'].unique():
    df[str(value)] = df['Gender'].map( lambda x: isValue(str(x) , str(value)))
```

Which works perfectly. But is there a better way to do this? Is there an inbuilt function in any of sklearn package that I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way to do this.  It's called `pd.get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(df)
```

[image]

To replicate what you have:

```
order = ['Gender', 'Male', 'Female', 'Unknown']
pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df, '', '').astype(int)], axis=1)[order]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My preference is `pd.get_dummies()`. Yes, there is sklearn method.

From Docs:

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
>>> enc = OneHotEncoder()
>>> enc.fit([[0, 0, 3], [1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]])  
OneHotEncoder(categorical_features='all', dtype=<... 'float'>,
       handle_unknown='error', n_values='auto', sparse=True)
>>> enc.n_values_
array([2, 3, 4])
>>> enc.feature_indices_
array([0, 2, 5, 9])
>>> enc.transform([[0, 1, 1]]).toarray()
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html